# Using symsum function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to solve this equation to find the value of Y, given that I have all other parameters.

The function is:

[image]

I have implemented the function this way.

```
f = @(x)-bond_price - accruedinterest + (principal/(1+x/200)^(N-1+(differenceindays/E)) + symsum((couponrate/2)/(1+x/200)^(k-1+(differenceindays/E)),k,2,N) + (couponrate/2)/((1+x/200)^(differenceindays/E)));
yield = fzero(f,0);
```

Error that I get is: Undefined function or variable 'k'.

btw how to find the solution such it is equal to zero?

Not sure whether I am  implementing it right. Need some guidance.

Comment: `syms k` maybe? Are you sure that you want to be using a symbolic math function in there? How big is `N`?

Comment: @horchler N refers to period max 100...

Comment: @eboix gives me this error at yield = fzero(f,0) now: ??? Undefined function or method 'isfinite' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

Comment: btw how to find the solution such it is equal to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably replace `symsum` with `sum` and do something like this:

```
differenceindays = ...
E = ...
bond_price = ...
accruedinterest = ...
principal = ...
couponrate = ...
N = 100;
k = 2:N;
DSC_E = differenceindays/E;
f = @(x)-bond_price-accruedinterest+principal./(1+x/200).^(N-1+DSC_E) ...
        +sum(0.5*couponrate./(1+x/200).^(k-1+DSC_E)) ...
        +0.5*couponrate./(1+x/200).^DSC_E;
```

I also removed a bunch of superfluous parentheses to improve readability. This should work with `fzero` (assuming that the equation has one or more roots as written). But of course we can't test it because it's all unknown variables.

Comment: @lakesh: yes, `fzero` can be used to solve for `x` given values for the other variables.